# Windows losing IPv6 address after ~10 minutes

Tags: windows-10, ipv6, asuswrt-merlin

When I initially connect to my home network my windows PC is assigned an IPv6 address - however after a few minutes it loses this address! I seem to have similar behaviour on multiple hosts using both wireless and wired connections.

My router is an Asus RT-AC87U.

How could it be losing the IPv6 address? How can I mintor / diagnose this issue?

**Update**:
Based on @grawity's suggestion below I ran wireshark on this. Sure enough I see a `Router Solicitation` message and a `Router Advertisment` message with a `Router lifetime` of 600 seconds. After 600 seconds my computer drops its Ipv6 address.

What is supposed to happen? Should my host send another `Router Solicitation` message? Or should the router periodically resend the `Router Advertisment` message?

**Update 2:**

- [RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#section-5.5.1) says that `Router Adverticement` messages should be sent periodically.

Comment: Using Wireshark (capture filter `icmp6` or display filter `icmpv6`), can you check how often you see a Router Advertisement, and whenever you see one what "ICMP→Router lifetime" & "ICMP→Prefix→Valid lifetime" does it show?

Comment: Have you tried Asuswrt-Merlin?

Comment: Go to [test-ipv6.com](https://test-ipv6.com/). If it says that your ipv6 ICMP is  filtered, then see [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/). If this helps let me know and I'll put up a detailed answer.

Comment: @grawity - looks like you were right, the router advertisements are timing out. I've updated the question.

Comment: @harrymc: That only tells one whether ICMP from WAN is filtered; it doesn't necessarily correspond to multicast ICMP within the LAN itself...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I figured this out:

My router has a flag that says `Enable Router Advertisement`. This was enabled - but by switching it to disabled (restarting) and then back to enabled (and restarting again) seems to have done something to the router and now wireshark shows it sending `Router Advertisement` messages every few seconds!

Comment: Every few seconds is way too often. (Drains Wi-Fi devices' battery, among other things.) Normally it should be every few minutes, with the "Router Lifetime" field being 2x-3x the interval. If you saw that "Router Lifetime" is 600s, expect the advertisements to be automatically sent every 200-300s (plus whenever a PC requests/solicits one).

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I have an answer, for those of you that don't have a "RA switch flip", in your router (I use a Cisco RV340 at home, an SMB router), so it's got a bit "more depth" in the IPv6 area.
I was really scratching my head over this, our Win10 machines were all losing their IPv6 gateways, at 50 minutes, give or take a few seconds, right after a whole slew of RA messages (monitored using Wireshark).
Turns out, it was my **Router Lifetime** value, which had worked fine, at the default 50 minutes (3000 seconds), for at least 2 years (I suspect my ISP changed something on their side here).
Changing to 5 minutes (300 seconds) fixed, this, completely, for 3 different (wired) machines, and one WiFi machine, I tested all of them for several hours, each.
This also greatly reduced the number of advertisement queries, in general, although I'm still not sure I understand why it had that effect (I'm still learning the nuts/bolts of IPv6, at least at-depth, the documentation isn't quite as "well developed" as IPv4, for obvious reasons).
Anyway, hopefully this clarifies things, and helps the next users who find this entry.