# Why my IPv6 address disappear after 1 hour?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ipv6

when I connect to my router, I get assigned with IPv4 and IPv6 and it works. But after exactly an hour or so, my IPv6 address disappears and now I only can connect with IPv4. If I re-connect or reboot router, it will come back, but still disappears again.

How do I fix this issue? I heard many people have same issue, is this normal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows losing IPv6 address after ~10 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/1376664/windows-losing-ipv6-address-after-10-minutes)

Comment: No. This's not the answer I'm looking for.